# What is the API method to return all records in a Dynamic Data List in Liferay 7.0?

Tags: rest, liferay-7

I am creating a React Portlet in Liferay 7.0. Part of the requirement is to read the data from a Dynamic Data List.

At first, it looks as though Liferay have provided the method as a Web Service to make my life simple but it seems that isn't the case.

Does anyone know how to return the records from a DDL recordset ideally in a JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay Portal provides remote JSON-WS services for almost all OOTB services. If you start your instance and go to `http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws?contextName=ddl` you should see all the DDL related JSON-WS services.

Have a look at "[Invoking Remote Services](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/invoking-remote-services)" and related documentation for details.

***UPDATE:***

In 7.0 there is indeed no method to get the records of a record set. It was added in 7.1  :(

So your best bet is to [create custom REST service](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/reference/-/knowledge_base/r/rest-template) to return those.

Comment: As mentioned above, 7.0 doesn't seem to provide get-records. get-record is there though :/

Comment: You are right. The method is not there in 7.0. You will have to to get the RecordSet and get the records from there. Worst case scenario - get the ids and call get-record for each.

Comment: @SeventiesKid please ignore my previous comment - the JSON of RecordSet does not contain the ids you need :( Your best bet it to create custom RST service. I updated the answer with a link to the documentation.